# Animation in JavaScript style.top value not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to achieve `parallax effect` where I have almost done but I have problem in Heading tag `<h1 id="text">Merry Chrismas</h1>` which is not animating. `<h1 id="text">Merry Chrismas</h1>` goes to top when scrolling.

```js
let text = document.getElementById('text');
let moon = document.getElementById('moon');
let snow = document.getElementById('snow');
let leftMountain = document.getElementById('left-mountain');
let rightMountain = document.getElementById('right-mountain');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let value = window.scrollY;

  text.style.top = value * -0.5 + '%';
  moon.style.top = value * -0.5 + '%';
  snow.style.top = value * 1 + 'px';
  leftMountain.style.left = value * -0.5 + 'px';
  rightMountain.style.left = value * 0.5 + 'px';
  btn.style.marginTop = value * 2 + 'px';


})
```

```css
/* To reset all margin and padding */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Now To remove horizontal scroll bar we have to use box sizing properties */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
  /* min-height: 100vh; */
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  color: #000;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  /* position: relative;
    z-index: 1000; */
}

.logo {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #ff556e;
}

header a.active {
  border: 0.125rem solid #ff556e;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  color: #ff556e;
}

.hero-section {
  /* position: relative; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.hero-section h1 {
  font: italic bold 4rem lato, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
}

.hero-section img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#base {
  transform: translateY(200px);
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ff0;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  transform: translateY(50px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <a href="#" class="logo">Chrismas</a>
    <nav id="navigation">
      <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Description</a>
      <a href="#">Features</a>
      <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section id="heroSection" class="hero-section">

    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/R605wLx/bg.png" alt="bg" id="bg">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/LZpM2k2/moon.png" alt="moon" id="moon">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/QnPgdXG/snow.png" alt="snow" id="snow">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/mGgD2s7/back-mountain.png" alt="back-mountain" id="back-mountain">
    <h1 id="text">Merry Chrismas</h1>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/wCx7SMd/left-mountain.png" alt="left-mountain" id="left-mountain">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/4YnDZTM/right-mountain.png" alt="right-mountain" id="right-mountain">
    <a href="#" class="btn" id="btn">Explore</a>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/3kdcSVZ/base.png" alt="base" id="base">


  </section>


</body>

</html>
```

[[**JSBIN Demo**]](https://jsbin.com/bekogehuma/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying to this:

```
text.style.top = value * -0.2 + '%';

#text {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

You can adjust to the speed that you need

Comment: With the last changes I performed at the code is what you need?

Comment: no.. the code you provided was merry christmas moving from upward to downward. I want result to be downward to upward

Comment: https://codepen.io/cr4id3r/pen/GRMxgvR

Comment: still merry christmas is moving from upward to downward vertically. I want to move from downward to upward vertically.

Comment: for example please see moon images